# Which sql database contains the item's display name?

Tags: sql-database

Please help me know which sql database contains the Sitecore's item display name?

Comment: Are you asking for the database or the table where the display name is displayed?

Answer (score 4):

The item's display name is a property (field) of your item. So it exists in the same database as your item. So I guess the answer is: all of them. You can find display names in master, web, ..

Just in case you are not asking about the database, but the table: you will find these in the `UnversionFields` (with FieldId `B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB`)